# How can you get the list of items that match a QSortFilterProxyFilter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a QSortFilterProxyModel filter items in a QStandardItemModel. I want to be able to see how many items match my filter. Is this possible?

I expect that if my QStandardItemModel has 10 items and my QSortFilterProxyModel only shows 4 after applying the QRegEx that the number 4 is queryable.

*Update*

This is for a QTableView

Comment: Is the model a list or a table?

Comment: This is for a table.